# Kotlin - can not infer generic type

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, akka

I'm working with Akka's `ask` pattern in Kotlin and I came across a problem regarding covariance. Here is the situation:

```
interface Token {
  // arbitrary stuff
}

class SpecificToken(override val underlying: TokenFound) : Token, ArbitraryInterface<TokenFound> {
  // arbitrary stuff
}

interface TokenRepository {
  fun find(): CompletionStage<Token?>
}

class SpecificTokenRepository : TokenRepository {

  val actor1 = getActor1()
  val actor2 = getActor2()
  val message1 = getMessage1()
  val message2 = getMessage2()
  val timeout = getTimeout()

  fun find(): CompletionStage<Token?> = 
    inquire().thenCompose {
      when (it) {
        is Inquiry -> Patterns.ask(actor, message, timeout)
          .handle { response, t -> 
            handleExceptions(t)
            if (response is TokenFound) SpecificToken(response) else null
          }
        else -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)
      }

   fun inquire(): CompletionStage<Inquiry?> = 
     Patterns.ask(actor, message, timeout)
       .handle { response, t ->
         handleExceptions(t)
         if (response is Inquiry) response else null
       }
}
```

Problem here is that `thenCompose` has a problem Java's generics I assume, reading:

```
Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter U in 
fun <U : Any!> thenCompose
(fn: ((t: Inquiry?) → CompletionStage<U!>!)!): CompletionStage<U!>!
None of the following substitutions

(((Inquiry?) → CompletionStage<Token?>!)!)    

(((Inquiry?) → CompletionStage<SpecificToken?>!)!)

(((Inquiry?) → CompletionStage<Nothing!>!)!)

can be applied to

((Inquiry?) → CompletionStage<out SpecificToken?>!)
```

What needs to be changed here, and if possible, could you explain why? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use old or new type inference?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (and obviously), `null` values need to be cast to `Token?` type, so changing the function to

```
fun find(): CompletionStage<Token?> = 
  inquire().thenCompose {
    when (it) {
      is Inquiry -> Patterns.ask(actor, message, timeout)
        .handle { response, t -> 
          handleExceptions(t)
          if (response is TokenFound) SpecificToken(response) else null as Token?
        }
      else -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture<Token?>(null)
    }
```

fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While you've found the solution, I think it's worthwhile to explain why it's needed.

`if (response is TokenFound) SpecificToken(response) else null` is `SpecificToken?`, so the `Patterns.ask(actor, message, timeout).handle { ... }` branch has type `CompletableFuture<SpecificToken?>`.

`null` by itself is inferred to have type `Nothing?`, so
`CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)` is `CompletableFuture<Nothing?>`.

Since your two branches end up with different types, the entire `when(it) { ... }` expression has their common supertype which is `CompletableFuture<out SpecificToken?>`.